# Sort List by date Immutable JS

Tags: javascript, unix-timestamp, immutable.js

I have a `Immutable JS` `List` with Objects. In each Object there is a key `date` with a `UNIX timestamp`

```
[{someKey: 1, date: 823748943}, {someKey: 2, date: 2389472938}, {someKey: 3, date: 81278734}]
```

How would I sort the List by date?

Comment: I think that you can use `sort` method anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Only a select few methods can be used in withMutations including set, push and pop. These methods can be applied directly against a persistent data-structure where other methods like map, filter, sort, and splice will always return new immutable data-structures and never mutate a mutable collection.

```js
var list = Immutable.List.of({someKey: 1, date: 823748943}, {someKey: 2, date: 2389472938}, {someKey: 3, date: 81278734});

var sortedList = list.sort(function(lhs, rhs) {
  return lhs.date > rhs.date;
});

console.log(list);
console.log(sortedList);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.2/immutable.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, but there is a immutableJS function to sort? https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/sortBy

Comment: Yes there is a sort function in immutable. Go through this documentation - https://www.npmjs.com/package/immutable

Answer (score 0):

You can create a copy using [`Array#from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and then sort that. This will not change the original array.

Also, `Array#form` can be used on ImmutableJS list, which will return the corresponding JS array.

```js
let data = [{someKey: 1, date: 823748943}, {someKey: 2, date: 2389472938}, {someKey: 3, date: 81278734}];

console.log(Array.from(data).sort((a, b) => a.date - b.date));
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Yes, but there is a immutableJS function to sort? https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/sortBy